# Is there a way, to make simple commands without the /trigger function with datapacks

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

So my problem is pretty small and the datapack I am currently coding as well.

I want a simple command, where on execute the executer joins a team and if he already is in that team, he leaves it. Very simple. It is for an Server of mine, where a prefix should appear on command, so the team option is probably the easiest.

Problem is, that the command should look like `/example` and not like `/trigger example`.
Is that even possible with datapacks, or should I just use a plugin?

The datapack structure is pretty small, there are only two functions, the one that runs on load and the one running on ticks.

The creaton of the team btw looks like this:

```
# This is the creation of the Team

team add live
team modify live prefix {"text":"live ","color":"red","bold":true,"italic":true}
```

Also, if anybody knows how to use only this one command like I said to enable and disable the team, so detect, wether a player is already in that team or not that would also help a lot.

Thanks for the hopefully incoming help <3

Comment: If you're on platform like spigot, paper etc, I suggest you to use a plugin yes

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no good way to create a command with a datapack without `/trigger`.

You can use a plugin however, you just need a [Paper](https://papermc.io) or [SpigotMC](https://spigotmc.org) server.
There are lots of good resources for making plugins, but in my opinion the most useful is [Spigot Plugin Development](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-plugin-development/) on the SpigotMC wiki. It details the entire process of making a plugin and is a good reference.